# Estructuración para Categorías de Productos

Tags: base-de-datos, optimización

Estoy creando la lógica de una app, donde se crean productos y cada uno tiene diferente categoría, en la lógica se selecciona la categoría y se obtiene un formulario diferente para cada una, el problema es como traspasar eso a una base de datos, que **ProductTable** tenga muchos campos para cada categoría, o separar por ejemplo para la categoría: **Vehículos** crear una tabla especifica y lo mismo con todas las categorías, **¿Cual es el enfoque mas optimo?**

Comment: Claro que lo tenés que separar, vos no tenés porque subir los datos de cada categoría a la tabla productos, va ser muy redundante si una categoría se repite en varios productos.

Vos vas a tener todas las categorias cargadas, y después en productos vas a tener un formulario donde creas un producto y ese va contenter el id de la categoria. 

Entonces tu formulario de producto quedaría con los atributos propios de productos más un select con todas las categorías y de esta forma no tendrias que tener problemas de guardar.

Comment: Creo que entendí que te referís a la relación uno a muchos (ya lo hice), mi problema es por ejemplo que hago si alguien selecciona 'autos', va a tener (modelo, papeles,combustible) y en 'ropa' (tela,talle,color), en la tabla productos va a tener todos los campos específicos de cada categoría, es poco optimo

Answer (score 0):

Primero habría que tener una definición objetiva de qué es "óptimo" en este escenario, pero voy a probar a dar dos posibilidades:

### El número de categorías está definido y no es muy grande

Una tabla para cada categoría con los campos necesarios, teniendo una relación 1 a 1 con la tabla producto. La tabla `producto` podría tener un campo `categoríaID` que nos indique qué tabla mirar o una columna ID para cada categoría distinta, siendo null para todas las categorías que no se usan para ese producto.

### El número de categorías es creciente o muy grande

Tienes una tabla `producto` con los campos básicos del producto, su ID, el ID de la categoría, fecha de inserción... y añades columnas "c1","c2","c3"... de tipo text/varchar, tantas como campos tenga la categoría que más campos necesite.

El campo c1 podría ser "tipo de vehículo" (berlina, sedán, SUV, todo-terreno) para la categoría vehículos y "tipo de prenda" (camiseta, pantalón...) para la categoría "ropa".

En otra tabla "category" tendrías el nombre de la categoría entre las columnas y el nombre de cada una según la categoría:

Comment: Hola pablo, las categorías son estáticas (10), me interesa tu primer enfoque, Categories tiene muchos Products, después ¿donde pongo la info de cada categoria? en por ejemplo ProductVehicle y elimino la tabla Product